# moved /usr and /home and broke it

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, symbolic-link, bind

I was doing [this](http://linux.chrissweeney.co.uk/topic.php?t=16) (i did "the hard way") to move both /home and /usr to the same partition on another drive with more space than I have on my SSD. When I renamed /usr all my icons and links broke and I couldn't call anything in terminal (eg. sudo). I couldn't even go on to rename /home. So I used a live usb to finish renaming it and make the empty /usr and /home folders. Now it won't boot and says it failed to execute alsact1 and alsact1 restore(). I'm guessing it didn't link /usr and /home to their new locations.

Any suggestions? I don't know much about what I'm doing here. Thanks.

Note: I want to successfully move the directories, not put them back where they were.

Comment: I would suggest a re-install unless you want to play around for hours to improve your understanding about what you are doing. Messing with system directories I would not even consider (and my experience goes back to Xenix).

Comment: Had to wikipedia 'xenix'. I would like to know how to do this for future use too. If I reinstall, I will have to make sure to somehow set up the /usr and /home directories elsewhere or i'll have the same problem all over again.

Comment: @Rinzwind I was cleaning up some disk space, and we were real low on the root partition. I noticed this one file hadn't been modified since we installed the system.... anyway, we don't need `/vmunix` right? Anyway, the server won't boot anymore... so if you could come in this weekend.

Comment: /vmunix: correct. might be a virtual machine(?)

Answer (score 1):

open ubuntu with your live media and then rename them back to the original and restart to your local ubuntu it should start to work again (at least all icons and links and terminal will start to work again).
If you've already moved them then move them back to their original directories

Comment: I can try that after a little while when I have time. I want to complete the move of the folders though.

Comment: should i assume that all the steps above the rename step completed without any error or warning

Comment: Yes. I ran 'sudo mount -a' before and saw the partition mounted in /mnt-extended.

Comment: may be the problem us that when you start your system the other partition does not mount properly did you put the mount command at startup

Comment: I don't know. 'No' if it didn't say to in the guide. That may be it. I found I could press arrow keys when ubuntu failed to load and it showed me some ouput - there were many lines like this:   
<br/>
/etc/rcS.d/37appanmor: 1: /etc/rcS.d/37appanmor: tr: not found
<br/>
only the number '1' and 'tr' were different in the different lines. For example, it couldn't find 'find', 'getconf', 'xargs' at various places.
<br/>
For the one I made, it said
<br/>
/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: S38bind.sh: Permission denied.

Then there were some other failures.

Comment: These mean that ubuntu is not able to find vital OS elements at startup also as you can see the command **bind** which can actually show the os where these files are is denied the permission, so that may be the main reason as to why your os is not working

Comment: Any ideas about how maybe to fix it? I've repartitioned the other drive and put a new version of 13.10 on 30Gb with two 50Gb partitions for /home and /usr but not my original ones, I had to start from scratch. I'm able to get on with life now but I still have the old install on the SSD drive I would like to get back into. I hate to give up on things like this. Also: thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i really don't think that you'll be able to perform those steps and get everything to work unless you are an expert linux user, the blog seems a little too outdated. That is there should have been many changes in the kernel and ubuntu itself, which will be a big problem. You may begin by looking for a newer blog This might help                  http://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/